# Error when installing node.js on Windows 8.1

Tags: node.js, npm, ionic-framework, windows-8.1, npm-install

I have installed node-v5.4.0-x64 in my Windows 8.1 PC. During the installation I got the following error but the installation completed.

```
Warning 1909. Could Not Create Shortcut Node.js command prompt.lnk. Verify that the destination folder exists and that you can access it.
```

And I am getting the following error when trying npm commands.

```
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have tried reinstalling node.js as suggested in some articles but it did not work.
I have searched for this error but I could not find any proper solution for this yet. Can someone help me please.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by creating the npm folder in AppData directory and reinstalling node.js.

I have followed the intructions given here.

https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/8141